# Laravel правило уникальности по двум полям не работает при update()

Tags: laravel

Есть правило валидации, которое гарантирует уникальность по двум полям в таблице с полиморфными связями.

```
'slug' => 'unique:slugs,slug,id,morph_type,App\Models\ProductCategory',
```

Все работает, но при редактировании категории не дает обновить поле `slug` - не проходит валидацию.

По идее я должно работать вот так:

```
'slug' => 'unique:slugs,slug,id,morph_type,App\Models\ProductCategory,morph_id,'.$category->id
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Undefined offset: 1

Кто-то знает решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
'slug' => [
   Rule::unique('slugs', 'slug')
      ->where('morph_type', 'App\Models\ProductCategory')
      ->where('morph_id', '<>', $category->id)

],
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Через Rule значительно удобней.

Comment: @VladislavChabanenko так же можно заменить правило exists